# Bring process to focus c# (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have created a web application that will call a window based application using:

```
    #region Process
    public static string shell_exec(string path, string args)
    {
        var p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.LoadUserProfile = true;
        p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.FileName = path;
        p.Arguments = args;
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        var pc = Process.Start(p);
        WindowHelper.BringProcessToFront(pc);
        string output = pc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pc.WaitForExit();
        return output;
    }
    #endregion
```

**this is published using IIS Express server**, the process.start() calls the application and shows in the top most (obviously because i set the property topmost true) but not in the taskbar (didn't activate the load event or not focused)
I also used bringprocesstofront function but didn't do anything:

```
    const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr handle);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr handle);
    public static void BringProcessToFront(Process process)
    {
        IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
        if (IsIconic(handle))
        {
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE);
        }

        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    }
```

am i missing something in my code?

The external process im calling is an application that will register a persons fingerprint (using DPFP digital persona, creating it in window based unless there is for web or javascript)

Comment: are you trying to control the client machine? if so you can't do that with a web app.

Comment: There is plenty wrong with this, there is a lot you haven't considered. If you have a valid use-case there is probably a better way to do this.

Comment: Im not trying to control the client machine the code will be run in the server itself. @DanielA.White

Comment: if there's a better way to do what it is? am a lil bit new in process method @slugster

Comment: Start by letting us know what this external process is actually doing, and why you want to call it from a web application.

Comment: On the server you won't be running as a user that has a desktop (and nor should you). You also can't inject your spawned process into the user space of a user who does have a desktop (well, you can, but not in this way).

Comment: Assuming your final production environment is IIS, this piece of code won't ever work as you wished, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Session isolation would easily break your attempt and like other comments said, give it up right now.

Comment: the external process is a application that will register a fingerprint @BrendanGreen

Comment: so it can't be achieve by the process method? @slugster

Comment: Presuming that the finger print registration is supposed to interact with the user - your current method is attempting to run the application on the **server**, not on the computer of the **user** accessing the website.  As others have mentioned, this is probably not achievable.  Sounds like you're trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool.  Let's get more detail about this finger print, why you are trying to "register" it, what it'll be used for, and what other systems you might be integrating into

Comment: The code actually runs the external process but not focused (as i mentioned). Im trying to register persons fingerprint so i created a window based application for that one (unless there's one for web). also Im using digital persona for the biometrics @BrendanGreen

Comment: Register a persons fingerprint ... in what?  Please update the question with this detail.  Comments won't allow enough detail about what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: I think the issue you are going to have here is you are in a scenario where you are testing as both the client, and the server. Anything you do on the server isn't going to be visible to the client, ever. If you open an application from IIS, you will never see it because the only communication channel you have to the user will be via the browser. Example: Your website opens up an instance of Word. Since you are testing locally you may see Word open. If you publish this to a server, you'll never see anything and the server may error since IIS is not an interactive login.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a UI for your process, or why you need a spawned process running on the web server. You could possibly achieve the same thing with a secured web service which you then call from your hosted web site.

Comment: the external application actually runs, it is visible in user but not in taskbar. im only asking if it is possible to bring focus to that process. @slugster

Comment: I think you might still be missing the point.  You firing off a process on the **web sever** will **never** be visible to the client, no matter what you do.  A website / web page **cannot** launch a process on the client in the way that you want.  You still haven't fully details what it is that you are trying to achieve (forget the technology and code for the moment).  There is likely other ways to achieve what you want

Comment: I just want to publish the web application in IIS Express that can call a window based application in the server side itself. @BrendanGreen

Comment: So we're still not getting clarification as to why you want to bring the process to the foreground, given that it's running on "the server side".  In a production deployment scenario, this would not be deployed like this.  Are you intending to deploy an application to *users* that runs inside *IIS Express*?